# Migration problems with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, server, redirect

We've got troubles with a migration of our website project.
We've migrated it to a local server (University) but we can't access to any pages of our website.
I think that's a problem of redirection with our pages. For the home page, we've got `error 404` and when we're trying to connect to the other pages, `not found, the requested url /index.php was not found on this server`. On the "original server", it's working perfectly but even if I hard code the new url of our server in `wp-config.php`, it won't work.
Any idea how to resolve it ?

Comment: What method you have migrated the Site from Local Server to Online Server. Could you please let me know...

Comment: @datahearth :- Have you have All URL in the database? and update permalink in wp admin setting?

Comment: We have copied files from OVH to our repository, then export the entire DB, configured it on the DB server then we've changed wp-config for our new DB.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar we have updated mod832_options for links in DB but what did you mean by permalink in wp admin setting ? Which files shall I configure for that ?

Comment: @DataHearth:- You need to replace all the URL in the Database with your new URL.
if your Old URL is "http://www.exmaple.com" and new URL is "http://www.welcome.com",  Than you need to update new URL in the database (Find and replace)

Comment: @DataHearth Yes in wp admin setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain to you the simple process when you transfer the wordpress website from an old domain to new domain. First of all upload all the files and in wp-config.php, change the db name, username, password and in some case db host too.

Now, go to the database and import the database of the old domain as it is.

After that you need to change the old domain to new domain. For that, you need to execute following four queries in the database.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Now, login to the Dashboard, hover on settings and click on permalinks. Change the current permalinks settings. It is necessary to change the permalink.

If you have not followed this process, follow it and let me know if you still get the error.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and let you know

Comment: well, now we've got 500 Internal Server Error. I've done everything you said. We didn't do the part of update the post and postmeta table and permalinks.

Comment: 500 internal server error will go, just change the permalink

Comment: Hey mates, thank you so much for that :D you helped us so much.

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "All in One Migration" Plugin from which you can export entire Website data and then install Wordpress and the same plugin in another domain or in localhost and there you can import the data. Go to the following link :
https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/